# Pod ReadinessGate for AWS Target Group not working "condition of pod readiness gate...target-health.alb.ingress.k8s.aws...does not exist"

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

We are trying to achieve zero downtime deployment in my kubernetes cluster.
We have an AWS EKS cluster version 1.20, and an AWS alb ingress controller version 1.1.4 (yes, I know it's an old one and we need to upgrade it :) ).

During deployments, we are facing 502/504 errors.
We found out the the cause of that is a lack of synchronization between the termination of the old pods, and the registration of the new pods to the **target group** behind the load balancer in AWS.
In addition, sometimes, it takes over 5 minutes (and even almost 10!) from the time that the pod been created until the controller is asking the AWS to deregister/register the targets.

We found out that there is a way to overcome it with the **Pod Readiness Gate**, which can make sure that the termination of the old pods will start only after the new pods are register to the target group and that its status as a target is "healthy".

We used the following documentation for configuring the pod readiness gate.
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v1.1/guide/ingress/pod-conditions/

To eliminate all interferences as possible, we created a new namespace called "afik-test" and deployed everything in it (beside the aws alb ingress controller that is the same for all the cluster and its under "kube-system" namespace).

**However, the pod readiness gate is not working and returning the error
message: corresponding condition of pod readiness gate "target-health.alb.ingress.k8s.aws/afik-nginx-ingress_afik-nginx-service_80"
does not exist.**

We know that there is a solution from the namespace scope with ALB Controller version 2, and although we are with version 1.1, I tried it too, but with no luck.

**Does anyone know what we are missing?
Are the EKS version is too high to use the old ALB 1.1 pod readiness gate?**

We used the deployment/service/ingress resources as are in the document, with the change of the names (adding "afik-" at the start of them).
Those are the yaml files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: afik-nginx-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: afik-nginx
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: afik-nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: afik-nginx-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /*
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: afik-nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: afik-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: afik-nginx
    spec:
      readinessGates:
      - conditionType: target-health.alb.ingress.k8s.aws/afik-nginx-ingress_afik-nginx-service_80
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

After talking with AWS, it seems like the AWS ALB Ingress Controller supports PodReadinessGate only from 1.1.6 (and also had important fix in 1.1.7).
After upgrading to 1.1.7 - all worked fine.